# ui-router ignoring state params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to implement a forgot password flow in my application that collects some information from the user and passes it through states.

After the user submits their employee ID and where they want a reset code sent to (email or phone), I send both of those to the token state:

```
$state.go("^.token", { employeeId: forgot.employeeid, resetType: forgot.resetType });
```

My router is pretty straightforward:

```
$stateProvider.state("authentication.forgot", {
  url: "/login/forgot",
  templateUrl: "partials/authentication/forgot.html",
  controller: "ForgotController as forgot",
  onEnter: function () { $(document).foundation(); }
});

$stateProvider.state("authentication.token", {
  url: "/login/token",
  templateUrl: "partials/authentication/token.html",
  controller: "TokenController as token",
  onEnter: function () { $(document).foundation(); }
});
```

And here is my token controller:

```
app.controller("TokenController", function ($state, $stateParams, $timeout, Authentication) {
  console.log($stateParams);
});
```

In my token controller, $stateParams ends up being an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying any parameter in the $stateProvider definition, put a url parameter or define the `params` parameter in the $stateProvider definition.

```
url: "/login/token",
params: {   object: {}    },
templateUrl: "partials/authentication/token.html",
```

Note than {} is the default value for object, in case no params are specified in the state transition, and you'll be able to access this via `$sateParams.object`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the params that you are trying to access in the state declaration.

```
$stateProvider.state("authentication.token", {
  url: "/login/token?employeeId:[a-zA-Z0-9]*&resetType:[A-Z]",
  templateUrl: "partials/authentication/token.html",
  controller: "TokenController as token",
  onEnter: function () { $(document).foundation(); }
});
```

You would then be able to access these in your controller via $stateParams.